# How to Disable inspect element in angular 4?

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui

I have a list of element but I want to display just some of them so I use this code

```html
[style.display]="!student.selected?'none':'block'"
```

But when I inspect the element I can see them all so my question is how I can change it with a secure thing??

Comment: If I have understood it right, why are you not filtering the Student[] into a clean one and display THEN just the student filtered?

Comment: I can do this, but I have a lot of code to deal with so I ask if there another solution for the moment to use it  if there not I will do the hard thing

Comment: Why not use `*ngIf="student.selected"`

Comment: Plus why do you invert the state of selected in your current code? It should be : `"student.selected? 'block' : 'none' "`

Comment: it's right thank you but if there is a solution for this i want to now it :)

Comment: The solution is to use `ngIf`, This is the proper way to conditionally show elements in the view.

Comment: yes thanks for remind me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *ngIf structural directive in your template (https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives). So in your case the component.html would contain:

```
<div *ngIf="student.selected"></div>
```

That would display the div element if a student exists.